# Pass php variable through JavaScript to another php page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I want to pass the `id` to the next page on clicking the entire row.
I tried to do it myself but I wasn't able to do so .
my code is below :

```js
$( "#tablerow" ).click(function() {
  var jobvalue=$("#jobid").val();
  alert(jobvalue);
  window.location.href = "jobsview.php?id=" + jobvalue;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
   <tr id="tablerow">
    <td><?=$srno?></td>
    <td id="jobid"><?=$row['ID']?></td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`val()` method works for form elements like `input`, `select` etc.

Use [text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/) method,

```
var jobvalue = $("#jobid").text();
```

**Update**

An `HTML` can have only one `ID` throughout the document. To enable click event for multiple elements and pass the one that is clicked onto another page, change `ID` attribute to `class`.

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="tablerow" >
     <td><?=$srno?></td>
     <td class="jobid"><?=$row['ID']?></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Then you can get the once clicked in `JS` as follows,

```
$( ".tablerow" ).click(function() {
   /**  $(this) will refer to current tablerow clicked
     *  .find(".jobid") will find element with class `jobid`
     *  inside currently clicked tablerow
   */
   var jobvalue = $(this).find(".jobid").text();
   alert(jobvalue);
   window.location.href = "jobsview.php?id=" + jobvalue;
});
```

Comment: But when i am using while loop it only works for first row.Can you help me solve the problem too.

Comment: Need sample structure with multiple values, and how it's been passed in JS under `location.href`

Comment: <?php

          while ($row = oci_fetch_array ($sqll, OCI_ASSOC))
            {
        ?>

 <td id="jobid"><a><?php echo $t = $row['EMPLJ_JOB_ID'] ?></a> </td>
        <?php } ?>

Comment: '
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

$( "#tablerow" ).click(function() {
    var jobvalue=$("#jobid").text();
    alert(jobvalue);

});
});
</script>'

Comment: Do you want to pass all IDs at once to another page comma separated?

Comment: only the one that is clicked

Comment: Updated my answer.